# Notifications of new answers to the threads in which I have posted?

Tags: feature-request

Checked the similar threads, this question wasn't shown there.

So, is it normal that we don't get notifications w.r.t the new answers to the threads in which I have posted?

If yes, then I would like to know the reasons.

Incidentally today I was browsing the Questions Tag and found another answer to that particular thread in which I had posted an answer.

The new answer may be enlightening for me, so I think it makes sense to issue a notification about the new answer to every poster of the thread.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea is to *not* spam users with information that they may not find all that interesting. Some users on this site have over 300 answers, that would generate an awful lot of notifications about new answers. And honestly, most people won't care about most of those answers.

However, there is already a feature in place that largely takes care of your issue: the star. If you like a question (regardless of whether you've answered), you can "Favorite" it by clicking the star just under the voting buttons. Once you've favorited a question, you will get notifications of any new answers. If you always want to know, favorite every question you answer, but I think you'll find that you really only care about a subset of the questions you've asked.

Comment: I click favourite star on those questions that are technically very ***important*** for me. I don't wish to clutter it. Can we have a choice in this case? I.e. those who want to get a notification can have it, those who don't can click the star?